# Cannot be blank fault but it isn't

Tags: infopath

First all i had a form that was working fine until a user emailed me today with the cannot be blank fault. I had not made any changes to the list or form since the last user had submitted it.

The problem is the fields are not blank and i still get this fault. I have tested on two different machines and different users and thee same fault.

I than edited the list to make no fields as required and now the form will not submit at all.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Just copy your template of InfoPath form and publish it again. Make sure you are calling the web service correctly if you are and they are accessible.